# Can I use WHERE IN when I have combined primary key?

Tags: postgresql

So if I have a table with primary key consisted of one id, I can update multiple rows by writing

```
UPDATE tableA SET colA = 'newValue' WHERE id IN (1,3,5,7,9)
```

Can I do it somehow if I have primary key consisted of 2 columns? I would like to update multiple rows providing some kind of array of keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
UPDATE 
  tablea SET cola = 'newValue' 
WHERE (id1,id2) IN ( (1,1), (2,2), (3,3) );
```